# Knockout JS 3.0.0 marking items in multiselect deleted when they shouldn't

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a page that creates a Kendo Window that has a Multiselect as a part of the window.

```
<div class="col-sm-9" data-bind="loadingWhen: isLoading.Participants">
   <select id="cmboParticipants" multiple="multiple" data-bind="loadingWhen: isLoading.Participants, multiselect: MultiSelectOptions, selectedOptions: Participants, valueUpdate: 'keyup'"></select>
</div>
```

The code bound that is used to populate the list is as follows:

```
    self.ParticipantsList.subscribe(function (val) {
        if (!val || !val.Other) {
            //clear the list
            $("select#cmboParticipants").empty();
            $("select#cmboParticipants").multiselect('rebuild');
            var empOptGroup = $("<optgroup label='Other' />");
            $("select#cmboParticipants").append(otherOptGroup);
            var rteOptGroup = $("<optgroup label='Other2' />");
            $("select#cmboParticipants").append(other2OptGroup);
            $("select#cmboParticipants").multiselect('rebuild');
            return;
        }
        var selected = self.Participants();

        $("select#cmboParticipants").empty();
        $("select#cmboParticipants").multiselect('rebuild');
        if (val.Other.length > 0) {
            var otherOptGroup = $("<optgroup label='Other' />");
            $.each(val.Other, function (key, obj) {
                $(otherOptGroup).append($("<option>", {
                    text: obj.Text,
                    value: obj.Value
                }));
            });
            $("select#cmboParticipants").append(otherOptGroup);
        }

        if (val.Other2.length > 0) {
            var other2OptGroup = $("<optgroup label='Other2' />");
            $.each(val.Other2, function (key, obj) {
                $(other2OptGroup).append($("<option>", {
                    text: obj.Text,
                    value: obj.Value
                }));
            });
            $("select#cmboParticipants").append(other2OptGroup);
        }
        $("select#cmboParticipants").val(selected)
        $("select#cmboParticipants").multiselect('rebuild');
    });
```

When i uncheck an item from the multiselect, I noticed that in the trackChanges code of knockout-3.0.0, the order of the items in the currentcontents is different from the order of the previous contents.  Specifically the code below:

```
    // Each time the array changes value, capture a clone so that on the next
    // change it's possible to produce a diff
    var previousContents = [].concat(target.peek() || []);
    cachedDiff = null;
    target.subscribe(function(currentContents) {
        // Make a copy of the current contents and ensure it's an array
        currentContents = [].concat(currentContents || []);

        // Compute the diff and issue notifications, but only if someone is listening
        if (target.hasSubscriptionsForEvent(arrayChangeEventName)) {
            var changes = getChanges(previousContents, currentContents);
            if (changes.length) {
                target['notifySubscribers'](changes, arrayChangeEventName);
            }
        }

        // Eliminate references to the old, removed items, so they can be GCed
        previousContents = currentContents;
        cachedDiff = null;
        pendingNotifications = 0;
    });
```

Since the order is different, I believe it is causing the items to be marked deleted when they shouldn't.

For example, I remove item e56 from the multiselect as shown in the two arrays below (note they are not in the same order for some reason)

Original Array:

```
0: "g3"
1: "e36"
2: "e46"
3: "e56"
4: "e55"
5: "e62"
6: "e58"
7: "e53"
8: "e59"
9: "e57"
10: "e60"
11: "e61"
12: "e54"
length: 13
```

Modified Array:

```
0: "e36"
1: "e46"
2: "e55"
3: "e62"
4: "e58"
5: "e53"
6: "e59"
7: "e57"
8: "e60"
9: "e61"
10: "e54"
11: "g3"
length: 12
```

For some reason, everything below the item i removed (e56) on the multiselect is now marked "deleted" by the getChanges call.  This results in all those items being deselected.

I know we are sorting the list when we retrieve the data from Ajax during the load of our viewModel with the following code:

```
loadParticipantsList(0, function () {
    var lst = [];
    $.each(model.lstOther2, function (index, item) {
        lst.push('g' + item.value);
    });
    $.each(model.lstOther, function (index, item) {
        lst.push('e' + item.value);
    });
    self.Participants(lst);
});
```

I imagine if i sort it before it gets passed to the trackChanges, it wouldn't mark things as deleted.  How do i catch the items and sort them before it gets to that point though?

Comment: This seems to be a pretty complex issue to reproduce - could you create a fiddle demonstrating the issue?

Comment: I'll try.  I inherited this code and am still putting my head around the whole thing.

Comment: Sometimes that also really helps to isolate the issue and fix the root cause instead of band-aiding it :)